# dApp. Как безопасно хранить приватные ключи в mongodb от кошельков созданных с web3.eth

Tags: node.js, mongodb, blockchain, web3.js

В приложении каждому пользователю привязывается адрес созданного кошелька.
Использование метода web3.eth.account.create() возвращает: 
{
address: "0xb8CE9ab6943e0eCED004cDe8e3bBed6568B2Fa01",
privateKey: "0x348ce564d427a3311b6536bbcff9390d69395b06ed6c486954e971d960fe8709", 
signTransaction: function(tx){...},
sign: function(data){...}, 
encrypt: function(password)
{...} 
}
Как обеспечить безопасное хранение приватных ключей в mongodb? Кто-то вообще хранит приватные ключи кошельков в бд? Если нет, то как правильнее поступить, база данных в любом случае должна быть.

Comment: приватный ключ на то и приватный, что доступ к нему должен иметь только владелец кошелька. аккаунт лучше генерить на клиенте, чтобы пользователь мог "переписать себе приватник на бумажку" а на сервер отправить только адрес

Comment: @muturgan, суть в том, что нам необходимо отправлять транзакции с этого кошелька, для этого необходим приватный ключ. Пользователю мы отдаем только адрес, он не может управлять им, это делает приложение.